# AWS IAM PowerUser Scoped to Specific Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-regions, aws-policies

I'm trying to create an AWS IAM Policy that gives access to everything that a Power User has (arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/PowerUserAccess) but only in a specific region.

I started with the existing Power User policy and found this article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_ec2_region.html

So I added the "condition" to the Power User Policy and the result is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "NotAction": [
                "iam:*",
                "organizations:*",
                "account:*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:Region": "us-east-2"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
                "iam:DeleteServiceLinkedRole",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "organizations:DescribeOrganization",
                "account:ListRegions"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This does not seem to be working as I can create EC2 instances only in the specified region... but other services are not available:
[image: CodePipeline]
[image: Lambda]

Comment: Have you tried `aws:RequestedRegion` condition? 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-requestedregion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `ec2:Region` in the Condition key, that's [EC2 specific](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonec2.html#amazonec2-policy-keys)

You'll want to try the [`aws:RequestedRegion`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-requestedregion) for the condition key.

Beware though,

> Some global services, such as IAM, have a single endpoint. Because this endpoint is physically located in the US East (N. Virginia) Region, IAM calls are always made to the us-east-1 Region

Give it a try with

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "NotAction": [
                "iam:*",
                "organizations:*",
                "account:*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestedRegion": "us-east-2"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
                "iam:DeleteServiceLinkedRole",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "organizations:DescribeOrganization",
                "account:ListRegions"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```